# How to merge 101 rasters files in R?

Tags: r, gis, raster

I want to merge 101 raster files into one with the .geoTIFF extension. How can I do it in R studio? I have files in one folder with .asc extension.

Comment: Is there anything specific about geoTIFF files? Or you need a solution on simple concatenation of binary files in general?

Comment: these are dem rasters with 1x1m pixel resolution, I need to merge them into one large geoTIFF

Answer (score 2):

You can see how it is done in the examples of `?raster::merge`. If that did not clarify what you needed to do, you should have at least built on that example and shown where you got stuck.

To get the filenames you do something like

```
fasc <- list.files(pattern="\\.asc$")
```

Create `RasterLayer` objects

```
library(raster)
x <- lapply(fasc, raster)
```

Now you have a list with RasterLayers. Let's create one for the example

```
r1 <- raster(xmx=-150, ymn=60, ncols=30, nrows=30)
values(r1) <- 1:ncell(r1)
r2 <- raster(xmn=-100, xmx=-50, ymx=50, ymn=30)
res(r2) <- c(xres(r1), yres(r1))
values(r2) <- 1:ncell(r2)
x <- list(r1, r2)
```

And with this list:

```
x$filename <- 'test.tif'
m <- do.call(merge, x)

m
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 60, 130, 7800  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : -180, -50, 30, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : test.tif 
#names      : test 
#values     : 1, 1000  (min, max)
```

This example assumes that all data sources have the same *origin* and *spatial resolution*.

Answer (score 1):

The code below merges .asc files into one file. If geoTIFF file needs something more than just merging individual files - you should provide that info.

```
con_write <- file('newfile.geotiff','ab')

max_file_size <- 1e6L # you may need to replace this number to something bigger then the size of a biggest single .asc file

for (this_file in list.files('path/to/your/files', '*.asc', full.names = T)){
  con_read <- file(this_file, 'rb')
  content <- readBin(con.read, 'raw', max_file_size)
  close(con_read)
  
  writeBin(content, con_write)
}

close(con_write)
```